# MySQL Import query that combines values

Tags: mysql, function, time, import

I'm importing data to MySQL from .csv files. Is there a way to combine rows with the same DATE & EMP if they exist and add the DURATION values so that each employee has one entry per day?  A more advanced version would add them together and if the value is greater than 08:00:00 it would enter the 8 hours in the "hours_reg" column and the remainder in the "hours_ot" column. Note that not all rows will have duplicates. I'm using MySQL 5.7. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The data:

```
!TIMEACT    DATE    EMP PITEM   DURATION    XFERTOPAYROLL   BILLINGSTATUS   JOB ITEM    PROJ    EMPLISTID
TIMEACT 9/21/2020   John Doe        04:00   1   0   Smith Residence     
TIMEACT 9/21/2020   John Doe        03:59   1   0   Smith Residence     
TIMEACT 9/22/2020   John Doe        03:31   1   0   Smith Residence     
TIMEACT 9/22/2020   John Doe        04:23   1   0   Smith Residence         
TIMEACT 9/23/2020   John Doe        04:00   1   0   Smith Residence             
TIMEACT 9/24/2020   John Doe        05:49   1   0   Johnson Residence
TIMEACT 9/24/2020   John Doe        02:24   1   0   Johnson Residence
```

My current query:

```
LOAD DATA LOW_PRIORITY INFILE 'D:/MySQL_Secure/payroll.csv'
INTO TABLE payroll
FIELDS OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '' TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS
(@ignore,@date,EMPLOYEE,@ignore,@hours_reg,@ignore,@ignore,JOB,@ignore,@ignore,@ignore)
SET date = STR_TO_DATE(@date, '%m/%d/%Y'),
hours_reg = STR_TO_DATE(@hours_reg, '%h:%i:%s %p');
```

The table format:

```
CREATE TABLE `payroll` (
    `id` INT(16) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `date` DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
    `employee` VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci',
    `job` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci',
    `hours_reg` TIME NOT NULL,
    `hours_ot` TIME NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=323
;
```

Comment: add yur casv to a temporary table and then you can use sum and group by to get you data, that is not possible during import